# How do I list all the new devices connected in Linux?

Tags: linux

I am thinking of using

```
 `udevadm`
```

but how do I use this to list all the devices newly connected.

Please suggest

Is this correct?

```
`udevadm monitor --udev`
```

Comment: That will list the devices that are handled by UDEV rules, which depending on your setup/distro will cover a majority of them.  Another option is watching the `dmesg` log since that shows basically anything (perhaps too much for your use?).  Something like `tail -f /var/log/dmesg`  Of course, if you gave us an example of what your application is, we may be able to better tailor it to your needs.

Comment: can i do something to just list any new hard drive connected or all the hard drives